# Python requests and beautifulsoup module not importing

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have installed python in my mac. When I type `python3`in terminal and then import requests and bs4 it imports it and run the program correctly.
But when I run it on python file as `python3 file_name.py`, it gives the following error:

```
 import requests
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
  File "/Users/dark_archer/Desktop/src/string.py", line 1, in <module>
    n1,n2=map(int,input().split())
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

I got the same error with both python 3.5 and python 3.6.

Comment: When you run your script does it prompt you for input or immediately fail without any action on your part? The error you're getting suggests you're not getting any input from standard input so there's nothing to assign to `n1` and `n2`.

Comment: in program file I have only written `import requests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you named a module `string.py` so it's confusing the importer because the logging module is also trying to import something from the standard library module `string.py`. This causes an issue known as "name shadowing" where your locally defined module is loaded instead of the the standard library module.

When your version of `string.py` gets imported it triggers the code which is causing your error.

As an easy fix, try to rename your `string.py` module to something else.

For more info on name shadowing check out the "The name shadowing trap" section of this link: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Comment: @user5516017 - No problem - this issue has bit me in the behind before so I'm glad to help. In the future you might consider checking https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html to see if your module names are going to override any of the standard library module names.